# Express, Mssql insert Into table with variables

Tags: javascript, sql-server, express

I can't for the love of god figure out how to add my Variables into a MSSQL server

I tried everything. Would someone be so kind and pls give me the answer how I can put my Variables into my Database?

I would like to avoid the possibility of a Sql-injection.

```
app.post('/addUser', addUser)

async function addUser(req, res) {
    let pool;

    const bodylength = req.body.length;
    console.log(bodylength)

    for (let index = 0; index < bodylength; index++) {

        const id = req.body[index].id;
        const first_name = req.body[index].first_name;
        const last_name = req.body[index].last_name;
        const active = switchToBool(req.body[index].active);


        console.log(id, first_name, last_name, active)

        try {

            pool = await sql.connect(config);
            const request = pool.request();

            request.input('id', sql.Int, id)
            request.input('first_name', sql.VarChar(50), first_name);
            request.input('last_name', sql.VarChar(50), last_name);
            request.input('active', sql.Bit, active);

            request.query(`INSERT INTO test (Id, first_name, last_name, active) VALUES (id,first_name,last_name,active)`)

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error)
        }
        res.status(200)
    }
}
```

I just get a 500 or UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Invalid column name 'active'. dependent on what I try.

Comment: I hope, column "active" is present in the table "test"

Comment: yes it is SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[first_name]
      ,[last_name]
      ,[active]
  FROM [users].[dbo].[test]

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work for what you need to do :

```js
...
request.query("INSERT INTO test (Id, first_name, last_name, active) VALUES ?", [id, first_name, last_name, active])
...
```

Comment: I get: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.